# html post form error / refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I keep receiving this error when refreshing a page after posting a form on my page.

I've tried a few suggestions that i found through google but none seem to have worked and still getting this error in multiple browsers. Any ideas what i could do to resolve this?

```html
To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier.
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="landingpage.php">
    Navigation colour:
    <div class="color-picker">
        <input type="color" name="navbarcolour" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $result['navbarcolour']?>"/>
        <br />

        Call & Working hours colours:
  <input type="color" name="navtxtcolour" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $result['navtxtcolour']?>"/>
        <br />

        Call & Working hours detail colours:
  <input type="color" name="navtxtcolour2" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $result['navtxtcolour2']?>"/>
        <br />

        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-md" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's an error. I don't personally use Firefox but in other browsers that occurs whenever you reload a form that you filled out. Try going to a different website and then going back. Hope this helps!

Comment: When the form is filled out and submitted, and stays on the same page if they try to refresh the page it tries to resend the form. It happens in firefox/chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try redirecting to a 'Success' page after it's validated & submitted. Don't really consider what you're getting as an error though...More like "as an aside" information.